# Import for Java or Other Languages that will Generate Flowcharts, Given Data

Tags: java, import, applet, flowchart

I'm trying to create an automated "spider diagram" like the ones created by VUE:

http://vue.tufts.edu/

VUE is open source, but the issue is that you create the maps *in* the program. I want to have a program that will pull the data from an excel sheet and display the map automatically when run.

I know how to open and parse the data in files, so reading the file isn't the issue. I can program the behavior of how I want everything to "link up", but I just don't want to have to create an applet, then develop the software from scratch.

If I made anything unclear, let me know. I'm very tired today, so it's difficult to stay focused very long.

Many thanks!

-Justian

Comment: Since its open source, if you don't have a problem exposing the source for your program as well then you could just pull out the parts that generate the graphs and write a program around that.  Since you are using an open source project though I'm pretty sure your project will also have to be open source.

Comment: I know I could do that, but I need to have this done relatively quickly. The source isn't well documented, so it's a little difficult to jump right into it. It'd be a lot more difficult to scrap away at a complete project then to build up from or work on top of pre-existing files that generally does most of what we need to do.

Answer (score 0):

[JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) is a library to do that. You give it the node and edges and it figures out how to present them in a meaningful way. It is kind of like using graphviz but in Java.

For visualization of production runs we use graphviz out of process and show the images generated from that. It works fine, but a single process solution would be better.

Reading an excel as CSV should be straightforward. POI allows you to read directly the Excel files.

Comment: It looks ok, but I think yFiles looks like a good option. Just to be clear: it -is- a library like you said, right? It looks almost like a standalone java program from what they're showing. How clear and documented are the classes?